# Python - List and Loop in one def

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the def wfsc_pod1 and wfsc_ip into the same def. I'm not quite sure how to approach the problem. I want wfsc_pod1 to display all the information for name, subnet and gateway. Then wfsc_ip shows the ip addresses below it. I also get a None value when I run it as it. Not sure why. Anything more pythonic is more appreciated.

```
class OutageAddress:
    subnet = ["255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.1"]

    # Gateway order is matched with names
    gateway = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4",
                "192.168.1.5", "192.168.1.6", "192.168.1.7", "192.168.1.8",
                "192.168.1.9"]

    name = ["LOC1", "LOC2", "LOC3", "LOC4",
                "LOC5", "LOC6", "LOC7", "LOC8",
                "LOC9"]

    def wfsc_pod1(self):
        wfsc_1 = "%s\t %s\t %s\t" % (network.name[0],network.subnet[0],network.gateway[0])
        return wfsc_1

    def wfsc_ip(self):
        for ip in range(100,110):
            ip = "192.168.1."+str(ip)
            print ip

network = OutageAddress()
print network.wfsc_pod1()
print network.wfsc_ip()
```

Comment: You generally want to inherit `object` rather than nothing so that you are using *new-style classes*, i.e. `class OutageAddress(object):`

Comment: What do you mean by getting the two methods "into the same def"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably meant to write `wfsc_pod1` like this:

```
def wfsc_pod1(self):
    return "%s\t%s\t%s" % (self.name[0], self.subnet[0], self.gateway[0])
```

and call `wfsc_ip` like this:

```
network.wfsc_ip() # no print
```

If you want to combine `wfsc_pod1` and `wfsc_ip`, you can do this:

```
def wfsc_combined(self):
    output = []
    output.append("%s\t%s\t%s" % (self.name[0], self.subnet[0], self.gateway[0]))
    for ip in range(100,110):
        output.append("192.168.1.%d" % ip)
    return '\n'.join(output)
```

and call this function with a print statement.

However, a better approach (IMO) would be to add print statements inside `wfsc_combined` and call it without a print statement:

```
def wfsc_combined(self):
    print "%s\t%s\t%s" % (self.name[0], self.subnet[0], self.gateway[0])
    for ip in range(100,110):
        print "192.168.1.%d" % ip
```

Comment: Still learning, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

`OutageAddress.wfsc_ip` returns `None` because it has no return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You get a `None` because that is what `wfsc_ip` returns. Functions/methods that don't return anything else return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You get `None` from `print network.wfsc_ip()` because `wfsc_ip` doesn't **return** anything, which is the same thing as returning `None` -- what **else** did you expect to get from printing the value of a function that just doesn't return anything?!

You seem to be in thrall to a deep confusion between *displaying* stuff (e.g. with `print` statements, as `wfsc_ip` does) and *returning* information, as `wfsc_pod1` does.  Until and unless you clarify that confusion, nobody can really help you much.